# Auto renaming of featured image filenames in WordPress posts..?

Tags: php, image, wordpress, filenames, file-rename

Please tell me, - is there a code I can use to automatically copy the title of a post and rename the filename of that post's featured image according to that title, putting dashes instead of spaces, removing special characters, and converting to lowercase, - basically the usual stuff that WordPress does to post names automatically... And all that at the moment that post is published..?

Thank you in advance!

Alex

Answer (score 2):

Hook into `save_post` to get the event when a post is saved

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'update_file_image_name' );
```

Then you can use the function `update_file_image_name`

This will pass you the ID of the post in question

```
function update_file_image_name($post_id){}
```

Use

```
wp_get_attachment_url($post_id);
```

To get the full path to the image. From here, you're just going to use that url by splitting and taking what you need to walk the directory, find the file, sanitize the string as you'd mentioned, and then return out when done.

Comment: thank you very much, though I'm not a coder and do not fully understand how to implement what you've written, so could you please describe in more detail, as to where to put this code and all the way to getting it to do what's it's supposed to do..? Thanks!